# How to draw the picture for the bounds of the double integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Given: The bounds assuming dA = dydx are 
$x^2\leq y\leq1$ and $0\leq x\leq 1$

Objective:
I want to find the $\displaystyle\iint_{D}\sin y\sqrt{y}\, \mathrm{d}A$ using dxdy because I don't want to use integration by parts so I'm reversing the order of integration.

I'm not sure how to draw the picture and get the bounds.

My work:
I think that if we integrated with respect to dxdy, our new bounds would be $0\leq y\leq 1$ and $\sqrt{y}\leq x\leq 1$. I want to check if my bounds are right.

Comment: In general you should try plotting all the bounds you are given, i.e., plot $y=x^2$, $y=1$, $x=0$, and $x=1$, and shade in the region that satisfies both inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the region,

[image]

It should be $0\le y \le 1$ and $0 \le x \le \sqrt{y}$